# _msize() on managed data arrays?

Tags: c#, unsafe, heap-corruption, unmanaged-memory

There is a native function wich takes arrays of pointers to data arrays e.g. char allocated with malloc.

```
void function(char** data, int nRows)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < nRows; i++) 
  {   
    int nCols = _msize(data[i]);    
    for (j = 0; j < nCols; j++)    
      char val = data[i][j]; 
  }
}
```

In managed code I have enumeration of byte[] arrays to pass to that function via PInvoke

```
unsafe void MyFunction(IEnumerable<byte[]> data)
{ 
  var handles = data.Select(d => GCHandle.Alloc(d, GCHandleType.Pinned)); 
  var ptrs = handles.Select(h => h.AddrOfPinnedObject()); 
  IntPtr[] dataPtrs = ptrs.ToArray(); 
  uint nRows = (uint)dataPtrs.Length;  
  function(dataPtrs, nRows);   
  handles.ToList().ForEach(h => h.Free());
}

[DllImport("function.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
static extern unsafe internal void function(IntPtr[] data, uint nRows);
```

However _msize call in native code leads to heap corruption. I remeber I used stackalloc with one dimensional array char* and concatenated byte[] arrays together.
But I need support for 'jagged array' with individual byte[] arrays of different sizes hence the need for array of pointers char**.

How to pin the byte[] arrays so that _msize correctly works as in stackalloc case?

Answer (score 0):

The memory was not allocated with something from the `malloc` family, hence `_msize` will not work.

This approach will not work when using C# to send data to the function.

**Edit:** Perhaps you should send along the column information as well.

```
void function(char** data, int nRows, int* colSize)
{
     /* colSize has nRows elems, containing the columns per row:
      * int nCols = colSize[i];
      */
}

[DllImport("function.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
static extern unsafe internal void function(IntPtr[] data, uint nRows, int[] colSize);

unsafe void MyFunction(IEnumerable<byte[]> data)
{ 
    var handles = data.Select(d => GCHandle.Alloc(d, GCHandleType.Pinned)); 
    var ptrs = handles.Select(h => h.AddrOfPinnedObject()); 
    IntPtr[] dataPtrs = ptrs.ToArray(); 
    var cols = data.Select(x => x.Length).ToArray();
    function(dataPtrs, (uint)dataPtrs.Length, cols);   
    handles.ToList().ForEach(h => h.Free());
    GC.KeepAlive(dataPtrs);
    GC.KeepAlive(cols);
}
```

Comment: I'd rather use it as a last resort. It was possible to use `_msize` with `stackalloc` but for one dimensional arrays. I wonder if there are managed functions allowing to call _msize on them?

Comment: There are not as far as I'm aware. I do a lot of P/Invoke work and learned to avoid mixing of unmanaged and managed memory whenever possible.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to invoke native `malloc` (the same native `malloc` as used to compile the other code, usually by linking to the same CRT DLLs) to make this work correctly, as C# arrays cannot support `_msize`. That means you will have to manage the lifetime of this `malloc`ed memory yourself.

Comment: I would not like to provide additional native functions for mem allocation with malloc to copy there managed data